# Get my instagram posts with the likes of a particular user mgp25/Instagram-API

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am use `mgp25/Instagram-API`

How can l get my instagram posts with the likes of a particular user?

My code:

```
set_time_limit(0);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$username = 'myInstagramUsername';
$password = 'myInstagramPassword';
$debug = false;
$truncatedDebug = false;

$ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram($debug, $truncatedDebug);
try {
    $ig->login($username, $password);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit(0);
}
try {

    $userId = $ig->people->getUserIdForName($username);
    $act = json_encode($ig->people->getRecentActivityInbox(), true);
    ???????

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Worked**

```
set_time_limit(0);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$debug = false;
$truncatedDebug = false;


$ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram($debug, $truncatedDebug);
try {
    $ig->login($username, $password);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit(0);
}
try {

    $posts = [];
    $comments = [];

    $userId = $ig->people->getUserIdForName($username);
    $maxId = null;

        $response = $ig->timeline->getUserFeed($userId, $maxId);
        foreach ($response->getItems() as $item) {
            foreach($item->getLikers($item->getId()) as $h){
                $posts[] = ['id' => $item->getId(), 'username' => $h->username];
            }

            foreach($ig->media->getComments($item->getId()) as $v){             
                if(count($v->comments) > 0){
                    foreach($v->comments as $c){
                        $comments[] = ['id' => $item->getId(), 'username' => $c->user->username, 'text' => $c->text];
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        print_r($posts);
        print_r($comments);

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try looping through each item of your profile then get the likes and find the username. Then if the item has a like by that user put it in an item array like so:

```
// Get the UserPK ID for "natgeo" (National Geographic).
$userId = $ig->people->getUserIdForName('natgeo');
// Starting at "null" means starting at the first page.
$maxId = null;
do {

    $response = $ig->timeline->getUserFeed($userId, $maxId);
    // In this example we're simply printing the IDs of this page's items.
    foreach ($response->getItems() as $item) {
       //loop through likes as u can see in [source 1][1] there is some method called 'getLikers()' which u can call on a media object.
        foreach($item->getMedia()->getLikers() as $h){
            // here do some if with if response user == username
        }
    }
```

source 1:https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/src/Request/Media.php
source 2:https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/tree/master/examples
source 3:https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/e66186f14b9124cc82fe309c98f5acf2eba6104d/src/Response/MediaLikersResponse.php

By reading the source files this could work i havent tested it yet.

Comment: but what this function getRecentActivityInbox()?

Comment: It returns the ActivityNewsResponse which can be found here: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/f3035e1aa3e9abce2c632a3b1f7cbd9bb0864de9/src/Response/ActivityNewsResponse.php

Comment: not `foreach($item->getMedia()->getLikers() as $h)`, but `foreach($item->getLikers($item->getId()) as $h)` worked. But `$item->getComments($item->getId())` don't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

for new version of mgp25 this code work fine

**POST UPDATED**

```
$likes = [];
$comments = [];
$userId = $ig->people->getUserIdForName($username);
$maxId = null;
$response = $ig->timeline->getUserFeed($userId, $maxId);
$posts = $response->jsonSerialize();
foreach ($response->getItems() as $item) {
    $likers = $ig->media->getLikers($item->getId());
    if ($likers != null) {
        foreach ($likers->getUsers() as $h) {
            $likes[] = ['id' => $item->getId(), 'username' => $h->getUsername()];
        }
    }
    $commentsList = $ig->media->getComments($item->getId());
    if ($commentsList != null) {
        foreach ($commentsList->getComments() as $c) {
            $comments[] = ['id' => $item->getId(), 'username' => $c->getUser()->getUsername(), 'text' => $c->getText()];
        }
    }
}
```

[updated reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281293/1830228)